# ucrtbase.dll crash whe using std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>>

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

The following code crashes every time the code runs. I don't see anything obvious of why it would crash. Help would be appreciated.

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>>> neighbor_count_filtered_clouds;

neighbor_count_filtered_clouds.resize(27);
    for (std::size_t i; i < temp_pointclouds.size(); i++) {
        temp_pointclouds[i].width = temp_pointclouds[i].points.size();
        temp_pointclouds[i].height = 1;
        neighbor_count_filtered_clouds[i] = boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>>(std::move(temp_pointclouds[i]));
        //*neighbor_count_filtered_clouds[i] = temp_pointclouds[i];
    }

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < neighbor_count_filtered_clouds.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << i << ":\t" << neighbor_count_filtered_clouds[i]->points.size() << std::endl;
    }
```

[neighbor_count_filtered_clouds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTBhY.png)

[temp_pointclouds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtpsC.png)

Comment: Where does it crash? Show the stack trace.

Comment: `std::size_t i; ` ? where is initial value ?

Comment: ***I don't see anything obvious of why it would crash*** This is where a debugger like the one in Visual Studio really helps. if you know how to use it. Although with that said I would expect the bug listed by @rafix07 to trigger a warning from your compiler.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks that was the problem.